# PEP8 import conventions

Tags: python, pyqt, pep8

I'm trying to stick to the best practices when it comes to import modules, I'm trying to understand what [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says about this.

Let's say my framework has hundred of classes and few dozen of packages. For instance, PyQt5 or sympy would be good candidates... what'd be the best choice from this set?

**a) Import everything**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

print(QPoint)
print(QPixmap)
print(QApplication)
```

**b) Import only big packages and using prefixes for the whole application**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

print(QtCore.QPoint)
print(QtGui.QPixmap)
print(QtWidgets.QApplication)
```

**c) Import specific classes from the big packages**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

print(QPoint)
print(QPixmap)
print(QApplication)
```

The option a) is discouraged by PEP8, what about b) or c)... what's the PEP8's recomendation about it?

Comment: I personal prefer b) if you are using multiple objects from a module, else a). But there is no rule for it in PEP 8.

Comment: There's no concrete answer. If I plan on using only a few objects from each module, I import them explicitly, as in (c). If I use a lot of objects from each module, I usually use (b).

Comment: It depends on context. I always use (c) in applications, and (b) in tutorials, examples, documentation, etc. I never use (a) - when experimenting in an interactive session, I prefer to use `from PyQt5 import Qt` (which puts *everything* in a single namespace). I don't particularly care whether my coding practices are well-aligned with pep8 (although I think they mostly are). The most important thing pep8 has to say is this: "know when to be inconsistent - sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment".

Answer (score 1):

There is no recommendation because it depends too much on your project, and what potential name clashes you may experience. If you don't already have a `QPoint` object (either of your own, or potentially from a different package), you may find it easier to read and write just the `QPoint` symbol where it is needed.

However, should you in the future interact with a different package that also provides a `QPoint`, you would need either to refer to them via their parent package, or use the `from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint as PyQt5QPoint` syntax before referring to `PyQt5Point` in subsequent code.